# Github actions - MacOS app bundle as artifact is not executable after download

Tags: macos, github-actions, app-bundle

I have created a Github action that builds, codesigns, notarizes and staples an Avalonia application app bundle. These steps do seem to work. As a final step, I want to add the app bundle as an artifact to the workflow. To do so, I move the .app bundle to a sub folder, and use upload-artifact to add the contents of the sub folder, i.e., the app bundle, to the artifacts.

To my surprise, after I download the zip file of the artifact, and unzip it, MacOS refuses to open the app. When I validate the code signing of the app bundle I unzipped using `codesign -vvv --deep --strict xxx.app`, the validation indeed complains that subcomponents are not signed at all. Very strange, given that the notarization etc completed successfully.

I'm reasonably convinced that codesign, notarization and stapling works fine, given that I can execute the steps locally, and de codesign validation succeeds. While building up the workflow, I did do attempts that failed because notarization failed. Locally I can execute the app after the necessary steps, but of course, it was not downloaded as was the case with the unzipped app.

After download, I added execution permissions using `chmod +x [bundle name]/Contents/MacOS/[MacOS executable]`, but this has no effects, which seems logical, given the preceding step with the validation fails.

I feel out of options of things I can try to fix this. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the way I add the artifact to the workflow execution. Anyone that can give me some tips on steps I probably need to take?

Answer (score 1):

That's what you get when doing this stuff late at night :-). The solution to this is apparently zipping the app bundle yourself, before uploading this as an artifact.

Comment: I guess you used `ditto` right? Because without it, I think you'll get issues with the symlinks in the bundle (if there is a framework in your project).

Comment: I did use ditto

Comment: Thanks! because I just used the upload-action on the .app itself and it took me a while to figure out why I had issues with code signing. It seems that the upload action uses the normal "zip" utility, and well, that does not play well with Apple Frameworks/Bundles. It seems that the symlinks were not created. This one was really hard to debug, gotta be honest.